# Vector equation of a plane through three known points.

Tags: vectors

I need the equation in **scalar product form** and **without using matrices** (Simultaneous instead).

The three points:  $A (2,3,5)$,  $B (-1,0,3)$,  $C (4,4,1)$.

I want to use the method where: the normal to the plane is normal to the three vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overrightarrow{CA}$.

So we get the three vectors $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{BC}$ and $\overrightarrow{CA}$ out of the points.

For example for the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ we do $A-B$ ... so $\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\5\\ \end{pmatrix}$-$\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\3\\ \end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

...so:

$\overrightarrow{AB}$= $\begin{pmatrix}3\\3\\2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

$\overrightarrow{BC}$= $\begin{pmatrix}-5\\-4\\2\\ \end{pmatrix}$

$\overrightarrow{CA}$= $\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\-4\\ \end{pmatrix}$

Now let's call the normal to the plane "$n$".

Since $n$ is normal to all those 3 vectors so:

$\overrightarrow{AB} \cdot n=0$ and $\overrightarrow{BC} \cdot n=0$ and $\overrightarrow{CA} \cdot n=0$

Now we can get 3 equations with 3 unknowns out and solve them to get the normal.

Let the 3 components of $n$ be $s$, $t$ and $u$ or $\begin{pmatrix}s\\t\\u\\ \end{pmatrix}$.

So, by taking the dot product, the three equations are:

$3s+3t+2u=0$

$-5s-4t+2u+0$

$2s+t-4u=0$

**I'm stuck here!** I can't solve those 3 equations. I can't get except one equation out of them. ...Where's my mistake? What's worng?

Comment: Hint: If you want to get the normalvector, you should use the crossproduct.

Comment: yeah I once read about the cross product thing on wikipedia. It gives the perpendicular vector to two vectors. @Danny

Comment: yes, and that is what a normal is.. :)

Comment: Sure but I'm tackling another problem here. I'm asking why is this specific method not giving an answer. I'm very puzzled why did I get a redundant equation (as John says)

Comment: So.. I'm sorry if my hint is unsuitable in your opinion. I just wanted to help you, because in genereal it is easier to compute a normal by the crossproduct..

Comment: no no it's okay. Your hint actually added up to my ideas ... it's just that it didn't answer the question. Thanks :D @Danny

Answer (score 2):

Nothing's wrong. Well,one thing is wrong: the vector $AB$ is $B - A$, not $A - B$, but that won't affect the result. And as Danny notes, the usual solution is to use the cross-product, but I'll follow your approach, since that's what you asked for.

The three equations *are* redundant: the third is a consequence of the first two. That'll mean that you don't get a unique solution, which is good, because if $\mathbf n$ is a normal to your plane, so is $c\mathbf n$ for any $c \ne 0$.

How do you solve an equation like this when there's one free variable? I pick two of the equations, and row reduce: 
$$
3s + 3t + 2u = 0\\
2s + t - 4u = 0
$$
Subtract second from first:
$$
s + 2t + 6u = 0\\
2s + t - 4u = 0
$$
Subtract twice first from second:
$$
s + 2t + 6u = 0\\
0s -3t - 16u = 0
$$
Now you pick a value for $u$ -- say $3$, to make the arithmetic nice, and get 
$$
s + 2t + 6\cdot 3 = 0\\
0s -3t - 16\cdot 3 = 0
$$
so
$$
s + 2t = -18\\
-3t =  48
$$
Hence $t = -16$, so 
$$
s - 2\cdot 16 = -18
$$
$$
s =  32 -18 = 14
$$
So a solution  is $(14, -16, 3)$.

Why pick a value for $u$ rather than $s$ or $t$? Because after row-reduction, $s$ and $t$ were leading nonzero entries in some equation.

Comment: Another way of putting what **John** is saying is that any pair of the three vectors you found already defines the plane (the pair "span" the vector subspace of that plane).  So a third vector in the same plane will be _linearly dependent_; that is why any third equation in your set is "redundant".  @John The linear algebra approach would be the "traditional" one; the cross-product method is a 19th-Century condensation of those calculations (and thank goodness!).

Comment: Okay so firstly my calculations are not wrong. (despite the B-A thing). ...I knew it can be solved this way; that is _getting an equation with 2 variables, picking one's value and calculating the 2 others_ but I'm puzzled about the fact that I got a useless equation out of "the third vector" for example. **How is that logical??!!!** @RecklessReckoner I don't understand the "linearly dependant" point. please please please explain.

Comment: oh and @John Thanks for sticking to my method. My concepts and tools _are_ very limited for the time being.

Comment: All right, your course isn't that deep into vectors yet.  For a plane, two non-collinear vectors are sufficient to determine a particular plane. A third vector, in that same plane, can be expressed as the _sum_ of a multiple of one of the first two vectors and a multiple of the second (what is called a "linear combination").  We then say that the three vectors together are "linearly dependent".  The way that manifests itself in a system of equations is that any one of the equations can be expressed as a sum of a multiple of one equation and a multiple of a second one. (continued)

Comment: In your post of the problem, the first equation plus the third equation gives (-1) times the second equation.  So your three equations together add up to " 0 = 0 ".  We say that such a system of equations is "dependent".  In order to get a useful result for your normal vector, you would only solve a pair of the equations simultaneously, leaving a "free variable", in the manner **John** describes.  That free variable is there because _any_ non-zero multiple of the normal vector has the same direction, and so is also valid as a description of the normal to the plane you seek.